# EmberJS + ember-intl: automatically generate additional locales

Tags: javascript, ember.js, localization

I'm using Ember with [ember-intl](https://github.com/ember-intl/ember-intl) for localization and have a `en.json` file that I want to translate into several different locales (different JSONs). Is there any tool that can help with this?

Initially I wanted to parse the source json file with a script and translate it by using Google Translate API. However, the parsing is pretty complex since `ember-intl` uses the **ICU Message Syntax**

Comment: convert into icu into json? https://github.com/messageformat/messageformat/tree/master/packages/parser

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use this tool. no ad, it can help you convert all the json to the right translation.

### codeandweb

https://www.codeandweb.com/babeledit

[image]

### poeditor

second tools:

this is also very easy, the google translate
https://poeditor.com/kb/how-to-translate-json-files

### Machine translation (MT) engines

### Translation management systems (TMS)

[image]

### Localization automation tools

[image]

### npm package translate:

you can use this package and setup json correctly to make json translate to generate all the file.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/translate-json-object

Hope this help. and let me know if there is any question. I can help